# OUT parameters from plpgsql function are NULL in function, but show when unit tested

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

Using PostgreSQL 9.5.

Here's the code in question, from job_parameters():

```
        SELECT
            j.controller_id
            , j.model_id
            , (
                SELECT cp.parameters
                FROM commit_schema.controller_parameters cp
                WHERE cp.parameters_id = j.controller_parameters_id
                AND cp.controller_id = j.controller_id
            ) AS _ctrl_par
            , (
                SELECT mp.parameters
                FROM commit_schema.model_parameters mp
                WHERE mp.parameters_id = j.model_parameters_id
                AND mp.model_id = j.model_id
            ) AS _mod_par
            , j.initial_glucose_id
        INTO
            controller_id
            , model_id
            , controller_parameters
            , model_parameters
            , initial_glucose_id
        FROM 
                commit_schema.job j
--         INNER JOIN 
--                 commit_schema.model_parameters mp
--                 ON j.model_parameters_id = mp.parameters_id
--         INNER JOIN
--                 commit_schema.controller_parameters cp
--                 ON j.controller_parameters_id = cp.parameters_id
        WHERE j.sim_id = sim_id;
```

When running this query with a fixed sim_id (used in the last `WHERE` clause) in a separate window, I get all of the rows I expect to be returned. The `SELECT INTO` moves the results of this query directly into the `OUT` parameters of this plpgsql function, but when this function is run, all columns except for the `sim_id` are `NULL`, which is due to the fact that the `sim_id` is selected earlier in the function.

At first I thought this was due to the keys I was using for the Inner Join causing the rows to show up NULL, so I opted for subqueries instead. This works when running this query on its own, but integrating it into the rest of the function  causes it to fail.

I've tried to troubleshoot using `RAISE NOTICE '%'` followed by individual parameters, but it doesn't seem to print to the console.

The full code for all relevant functions is here:

```
DROP DOMAIN IF EXISTS computer_name CASCADE;
CREATE DOMAIN computer_name AS varchar(50);

DROP TYPE IF EXISTS error_cluster CASCADE;
CREATE TYPE error_cluster AS (
    error_code integer
    , error_msg varchar(100)
);

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS select_client_id(computer_name);
CREATE FUNCTION select_client_id (
    IN clean_name computer_name DEFAULT 'none'
    , OUT client_id integer
    )
    AS $$
    BEGIN
        SELECT c.client_id INTO client_id
        FROM commit_schema.client c
        WHERE c.client_name = $1
        LIMIT 1;
    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS get_client_id(computer_name, error_cluster);
CREATE FUNCTION get_client_id (
    IN clean_name computer_name DEFAULT 'none'
    , IN error_in error_cluster DEFAULT (0,'')
    , OUT _client_id integer
    , OUT error_out error_cluster)
    AS $$
    BEGIN
        SELECT client_id INTO _client_id
        FROM select_client_id(clean_name);
        IF _client_id IS NULL THEN
            INSERT INTO commit_schema.client (client_name) VALUES (clean_name);
            SELECT client_id INTO _client_id
            FROM select_client_id(clean_name);
        END IF;
        IF _client_id IS NULL THEN
            SELECT
                -10000
                , 'No Client ID found after Client Name insert.'
            INTO
                error_out.error_code
                , error_out.error_msg;
        ELSE
            SELECT
                error_in.error_code
                , error_in.error_msg
            INTO
                error_out.error_code
                , error_out.error_msg;
        END IF;
    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

/*
    Get a simulation ID
*/

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS get_sim_id(error_cluster);
CREATE FUNCTION get_sim_id(
    IN error_in error_cluster
    , OUT _sim_id integer
    , OUT error_out error_cluster)
    AS $$
    BEGIN
        -- SELECT
--             MIN(j.sim_id)
--         INTO
--             _sim_id
--         FROM commit_schema.job j
--         WHERE j.job_status_id = 0;
        UPDATE commit_schema.job j
        SET job_status_id = 1
        FROM (
                SELECT sim_id
                FROM commit_schema.job
                WHERE job_status_id = 0
                ORDER BY sim_id
                LIMIT 1
                FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
        ) sub
        WHERE j.sim_id = sub.sim_id
        RETURNING j.sim_id INTO _sim_id;
        IF NOT FOUND THEN
            SELECT
                -10000
                , 'No more jobs left to run!'
                , -1
            INTO
                error_out.error_code
                , error_out.error_msg
                , _sim_id;
        ELSE
            SELECT
                error_in.error_code
                , error_in.error_msg
            INTO
                error_out.error_code
                , error_out.error_msg;
        END IF;
    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS set_job_status(integer, smallint, error_cluster);
CREATE FUNCTION set_job_status(
    IN sim_id integer
    , IN status smallint
    , IN error_in error_cluster
    , OUT error_out error_cluster)
    AS $$
    BEGIN
        UPDATE commit_schema.job j
        SET j.job_status_id = $2
        WHERE j.sim_id = $1;
        IF NOT FOUND THEN
            SELECT
                -10000
                , 'No job with sim_id='||$1
            INTO
                error_out.error_code
                , error_out.error_msg;
        ELSE
            SELECT
                error_in.error_code
                , error_in.error_msg
            INTO
                error_out.error_code
                , error_out.error_msg;
        END IF;
    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS set_job_status_to_pending(integer, error_cluster);
CREATE FUNCTION set_job_status_to_pending(
    IN sim_id integer
    , IN error_in error_cluster
    , OUT error_out error_cluster)
    AS $$
    BEGIN
        SELECT
            sj.error_out.error_code
            , sj.error_out.error_msg
        INTO
            error_out.error_code
            , error_out.error_msg
        FROM set_job_status($1, 1, error_in.*) sj;
    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS set_job_status_to_running(integer, error_cluster);
CREATE FUNCTION set_job_status_to_running(
    IN sim_id integer
    , IN error_in error_cluster
    , OUT error_out error_cluster)
    AS $$
    BEGIN
        SELECT
            sj.error_out.error_code
            , sj.error_out.error_msg
        INTO
            error_out.error_code
            , error_out.error_msg
        FROM set_job_status($1, 2, error_in.*) sj;
    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS reset_job_status(integer, error_cluster);
CREATE FUNCTION reset_job_status(
    IN sim_id integer
    , IN error_in error_cluster
    , OUT error_out error_cluster)
    AS $$
    BEGIN
        SELECT
            sj.error_out.error_code
            , sj.error_out.error_msg
        INTO
            error_out.error_code
            , error_out.error_msg
        FROM set_job_status($1, 0, error_in.*) sj;
    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS job_parameters(computer_name);
CREATE FUNCTION job_parameters (
    IN computer_id computer_name DEFAULT 'none'
    , OUT controller_id integer
    , OUT sim_id integer
    , OUT controller_parameters integer ARRAY
    , OUT model_id integer
    , OUT model_parameters integer ARRAY
    , OUT initial_glucose_id integer
    , OUT final_error_code integer
    , OUT final_error_msg varchar(100))
    AS $$
    DECLARE
        -- get rid of garbage in the name we receive
        clean_name computer_name := lower(regexp_replace(computer_id, '\W+', '', 'g'));
        current_error error_cluster;
        error_out error_cluster;
    BEGIN
        SELECT
            0
            , ''
        INTO
            current_error.error_code
            , current_error.error_msg;
        -- -- See if the incoming client already has a client_id
        -- -- If it does, use that. Else give it a new one.
        SELECT
            error_out.error_msg
            , error_out.error_code
        INTO
            current_error.error_msg
            , current_error.error_code
        FROM get_client_id(clean_name, current_error.*);

        -- Get a simulation ID
        SELECT
            _sim_id
            , error_out.error_msg
            , error_out.error_code
        INTO
            sim_id
            , current_error.error_msg
            , current_error.error_code
        FROM get_sim_id(current_error.*);

        IF current_error <> (0,'') THEN
            SELECT
                current_error.error_code
                , current_error.error_msg
            INTO
                final_error_code
                , final_error_msg;
            RETURN;
        END IF;

--         -- Set the job to pending
--         SELECT
--             error_out.error_code
--             , error_out.error_msg
--         INTO
--             current_error.error_code
--             , current_error.error_msg
--         FROM set_job_status_to_pending(sim_id, current_error.*);

--         IF current_error <> (0,'') THEN
--             SELECT
--                 current_error.error_code
--                 , current_error.error_msg
--             INTO
--                 final_error_code
--                 , final_error_msg;
--             RETURN;
--         END IF;

        -- Get the parameters
        SELECT
            j.controller_id
            , j.model_id
            , (
                SELECT cp.parameters
                FROM commit_schema.controller_parameters cp
                WHERE cp.parameters_id = j.controller_parameters_id
                AND cp.controller_id = j.controller_id
            ) AS _ctrl_par
            , (
                SELECT mp.parameters
                FROM commit_schema.model_parameters mp
                WHERE mp.parameters_id = j.model_parameters_id
                AND mp.model_id = j.model_id
            ) AS _mod_par
            , j.initial_glucose_id
        INTO
            controller_id
            , model_id
            , controller_parameters
            , model_parameters
            , initial_glucose_id
        FROM 
                commit_schema.job j
--         INNER JOIN 
--                 commit_schema.model_parameters mp
--                 ON j.model_parameters_id = mp.parameters_id
--         INNER JOIN
--                 commit_schema.controller_parameters cp
--                 ON j.controller_parameters_id = cp.parameters_id
        WHERE j.sim_id = sim_id;
        RAISE NOTICE 'mp: % cp: % simid: %', model_parameters, controller_parameters, sim_id;

        IF NOT FOUND THEN
            SELECT
                current_error.error_msg || 'No row found for sim_id ' || sim_id ||'. '
                , -10000
            INTO
                final_error_msg
                , final_error_code;
            RETURN;
        END IF;

        IF controller_id IS NULL THEN
            SELECT
                current_error.error_msg || 'No Controller ID found for this sim_id. '
                , -10000
            INTO
                current_error.error_msg
                , current_error.error_code;
        END IF;

        IF model_id IS NULL THEN
            SELECT
                current_error.error_msg || 'No Model ID found for this sim_id. '
                , -10000
            INTO
                current_error.error_msg
                , current_error.error_code;
        END IF;

        IF controller_parameters IS NULL THEN
            SELECT
                current_error.error_msg || 'No Controller Parameters found for this sim_id. '
                , -10000
            INTO
                current_error.error_msg
                , current_error.error_code;
        END IF;

        IF model_parameters IS NULL THEN
            SELECT
                current_error.error_msg || 'No Model Parameters found for this sim_id. '
                , -10000
            INTO
                current_error.error_msg
                , current_error.error_code;
        END IF;

        IF current_error = (0,'') THEN
        -- If everything went well, set job to running
            SELECT
                error_out.error_code
                , error_out.error_msg
            INTO
                current_error.error_code
                , current_error.error_msg
            FROM set_job_status_to_running(sim_id, current_error.*);
        ELSE
        -- Otherwise we reset the simid
            SELECT
                error_out.error_code
            INTO current_error
            FROM reset_job_status(sim_id, current_error.*);
        END IF;

        SELECT
            current_error.error_msg
            , current_error.error_code
        INTO
            final_error_msg
            , final_error_code;

    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: You should really post the entire function for anyone to properly understand what the problem - and the solution - is.

Comment: Updated the OP with full function creation script. Warning: it's not very pretty.

Comment: There is just too much (possibly unrelated) code in the question. SO is not for code review, it's a Q/A site.

Comment: Thanks Erwin. I originally had just what I thought was relevant, but the prior comment had asked for the full script.

Comment: Yeah, some problems are hard to pin down ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `set_job_status(...)` has a syntax error:

```
CREATE FUNCTION set_job_status(
    IN sim_id integer
    , IN status smallint
    , IN error_in error_cluster
    , OUT error_out error_cluster)
    AS $$
    BEGIN
        UPDATE commit_schema.job j
        SET j.job_status_id = $2  -- invalid!!
        WHERE j.sim_id = $1;
```

You cannot table-qualify column names in the `SET` clause of an `UPDATE`. Must be:

```
        SET job_status_id = $2
```

Not sure if that's all, I stopped looking there.